# How to continue save the history of validation loss in Keras

Tags: keras, history

Let say I want to train with 100 epoch. But after 50 epoch, I would like to save the model once every 5 epoch. I also would like to save the history as well. I wasn't sure how to do it, so I did something like below. Please let me know how to continue to save history.

```
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_split = 0.2, shuffle=True, batch_size=gb.BATCH_SIZE, epochs=50)

counters = gb.EPOCHS_COUNT  // 5

for counter in range(counters):
    history += model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_split = 0.2, shuffle=True, batch_size=gb.BATCH_SIZE, epochs=5)
    modelName = "model_weights_total_0"+str(counter)+".h5"
    model.save(model_save_path+modelName, overwrite=True)
```

Comment: You can use Keras callbacks to save your weights after each epoch. You see this example here: https://machinelearningmastery.com/check-point-deep-learning-models-keras/
Also, there's a lot you can do with callbacks that are very interesting to know https://keras.io/callbacks/

Answer (score 0):

One way is to sum `history.history` values manually.

```
val_losses = []
for counter in range(counters):
    history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_split = 0.2, shuffle=True, batch_size=gb.BATCH_SIZE, epochs=5)
    val_losses += history.history['val_loss']
```